# Kotlin, Implementing two interfaces with same method and have default values

Tags: android, kotlin

Let's say I have Two interfaces with same method name and signature and have default value for its parameter, implemented by a single class there will be a compilation error:

> More than one overridden descriptor declares a default value for
> 'value-parameter b: Boolean = ... As the compiler can not make sure
> these values agree, this is not allowed.

Ex:

```
    interface A {
    fun f(b: Boolean = true)
    }

    interface B {
    fun f(b: Boolean = false)
    }

    class C : A, B {

    override fun f(b: Boolean) {

      }
   }
```

Is there a way to solve this issue or should I define two different methods

Comment: i feel like it would be quite annoying from a development point of view if you had to constantly figure out which method is actually being used or called when you type it, renaming one feels like it would make the most sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this. because the implementor method can not have a default value. and if you use `C().f()` how the compiler is going to know use which default value?
because `C()` is An `A` and it is Also a `B`.

`C().f()` has to call `C.f(true)` because true is the default value in A.
and
`C().f()` also has to call `C().f(false)` because false is default value in B.
so it is a conflict and it is not allowed.

You can do something like this to achieve what you want :

```
interface A {
fun f(b)
fun f(){f(true)}
}

interface B {
fun f(b)
fun f(){f(false)}
}

class C : A, B {

override fun f(b: Boolean) {

}
override fun f() {
// now you can define which default value is used for class C 
// You can define either true or false
f(true)
}

}
```